# json exception in kotlin app

Tags: json, kotlin

I'm trying to read a JSON file in a kotlin app. I can read the json but there's an error, it doesn't fill the array. When it shows the exception, I can see the json result. Here is the code:

```
 fun read(){
    val stringRequest = StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, Response.Listener<String>{s ->
        try {
            val obj = JSONObject(s)
            if(!obj.getBoolean("error")){
                val array = obj.getJSONArray("friend")

                for(i in 0..array.length()-1){
                    val objectFriend = array.getJSONObject(i)
                    val friend = Friend(objectFriend.getString("name"), objectFriend.getString("surname"))

                    listaPersonas.add(friend)

                }
            }
        }catch (e: JSONException){
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    },Response.ErrorListener { error: VolleyError? -> Log.e("error", "error")  })

    val  requesQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this)
    requesQueue.add<String>(stringRequest)


}
```

This is the exception:

```
org.json.JSONException: Value [value of json] of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject
09-30 22:25:06.241 17310-17310/com.example.user.kotlinjson W/System.err:     at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)
09-30 22:25:06.242 17310-17310/com.example.user.kotlinjson W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:160)
09-30 22:25:06.242 17310-17310/com.example.user.kotlinjson W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:173)
09-30 22:25:06.242 17310-17310/com.example.user.kotlinjson W/System.err:     at com.example.smoreno.kotlinprueba.MainActivity$read$stringRequest$1.onResponse(MainActivity.kt:139)
09-30 22:25:06.242 17310-17310/com.example.smoreno.kotlinprueba W/System.err:     at com.example.smoreno.kotlinprueba.MainActivity$read$stringRequest$1.onResponse(MainActivity.kt:22)
09-30 22:25:06.242 17310-17310/com.example.smoreno.kotlinprueba W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:60)
09-30 22:25:06.242 17310-17310/com.example.smoreno.kotlinprueba W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:30)
```

Comment: Where's the exception? Can't see it.

Comment: sorry, it's posted now

Answer (score 0):

There is possibility you getting JsonArray as response with empty or null value and you trying to cast as JsonObject. Try given code below.

Replace

```
val obj = JSONObject(s)
```

With

```
if(s != null && s.isNotEmpty()) {
val obj = JSONArray(s)
// rest of code here
}
```